# Evaluating Imagenet accuracy of TF Lite models with official tool

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I used the official Imagenet accuracy evaluation tool at tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/evaluation/tasks/imagenet_image_classification/ on the official quantized MobileNet V2. However, the reported accuracy is far below the expected. The MB V2 is downloaded from https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quantized/1/default/1. The run settings below have followed the [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5dcfc51118817f27fad5246812d83e5dccdc5f72/tensorflow/lite/tools/evaluation/tasks/imagenet_image_classification/README.md) as much as possible. Please help explain the accuracy gap.

Command:

```
bazel run -c opt \
-- \
//tensorflow/lite/tools/evaluation/tasks/imagenet_image_classification:run_eval \
--model_file=/home/ubuntu/workspace/tensorflow/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quantized_1_default_1.tflite \
--ground_truth_images_path=${IMAGENET_IMAGES_DIR} \
--ground_truth_labels=${VALIDATION_LABELS} \
--model_output_labels=${MODEL_LABELS_TXT_LONG} \
--output_file_path=/tmp/accuracy_output.txt \
--num_interpreter_threads=4 \
--num_images=0
```

Output:

```
Num evaluation runs: 50000
Preprocessing latency: avg=7697.15(us), std_dev=0(us)
Inference latency: avg=77301.9(us), std_dev=6485(us)
Top-1 Accuracy: 0.35942
Top-2 Accuracy: 0.41372
Top-3 Accuracy: 0.43532
Top-4 Accuracy: 0.4475
Top-5 Accuracy: 0.4553
Top-6 Accuracy: 0.46088
Top-7 Accuracy: 0.46498
Top-8 Accuracy: 0.46842
Top-9 Accuracy: 0.47142
Top-10 Accuracy: 0.4736
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the v1 model that's specified on the instruction document? If that's working fine I'd suspect the difference of data preprocessing before the insertion for inferencing, otherwise the instruction should be reported as a bug I guess.